# Boundary of subset of continuous functions with supreme norm

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space of continuous functions on the set $[0,1]$ with values $[0,1]$ with the metric
\begin{equation}
d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|.
\end{equation}
with induced topology.

Let $Y$ be a subset of functions $f$ with $f(0) \neq 0$ and $f(1) > 1/2$.

I want to find a boundary of $Y$

**Ideas:**
$\text{Boundary of } Y = \operatorname{closure}(Y)\smallsetminus\operatorname{interior}(Y).$

$\operatorname{Cl}(Y) = Y \cup Y'$, where $Y'$ is a set of limit points of $Y$. Because $Y$ is subset of $X$ by definition of induced topology $Y$ is open. It means that $X - Y$ is closed and contains some limit points of $Y$ (definition of closed set). So basically it means: $\operatorname{cl}(Y) = Y \cup (X-Y)'$

By definition of induced topology: $Y \subset X$, s.t for all $x \in Y$ exist $B \in$ ***B***, s.t $x \in B \subseteq Y$.

Interior set is union of all  open balls which are completely contained in S. So interior of $Y$ is $Y$.

**Comment:** Can you please tell me if I am going in the right direction? I can be for sure completely false and don't blame me for that please. But if my ideas are correct - how should I proceed further?

Any corrections are welcome.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle d(f,g)=sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|$ to $\displaystyle d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|.$ That$\vphantom{\dfrac{}{\displaystyle\int}}$ is standard usage and requires only one additional keystroke. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you for corrections. But have some comments about my question?

Comment: My first guess is functions $f$ for which $f(0)=0$ or $f(1) = 1/2$ would be on the boundary.

Comment: @GabrielRomon : I inteded my comment to be read within the context of the question.

Comment: @DanielYefimov Is $Y$ _the_ set of functions with [...] or _a_ set of functions with [...]? There is a big difference - also concerning your boundary. I guess you mean _the_?

Comment: I continuous function from $[0,1]$ to itself is on the boundary of this set if and only if its every open neighborhood intersects both this set and  its comlement. That means for every $\varepsilon>0,$ there are continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to itself whose distance from a function on the boundary is less than $\varepsilon$ and are in this set, and there are others whose distance from that function on the boundary are less than $\varepsilon$ and are _not_ in this set.

Comment: @amsmath the set of functions. But what is the difference? I am not native english speaker:)

Comment: @DanielYefimov Ok, this is important: "A set" means "some set", while "the set" is a specific set. So if you say that $Y$ is THE set of functions $f$ with $f(1) > 1/2$, it means that $Y$ contains ALL functions with that property. On the other hand, when you say $Y$ is A set with all $f$ satisfying $f(1) > 1/2$, then $Y$ is just some set with functions satisfying this. There might be just one function inside $Y$. I hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1/2.$ Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Let $g(x) = \max\{1,f(x) + \varepsilon/2\}.$ Then $g\in Y$ and $d(f,g)<\varepsilon.$ Let $h(x)= \min\{f(x) - \varepsilon x/2,0\}.$

Then $h\notin Y$ and $d(f,h)<\varepsilon.$

So the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f$ contains both points in $Y$ and points not in $Y.$ This is true no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is. Therefore $f$ is on the boundary of $Y.$

Next, suppose $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous and $f(1)<1/2.$ Let $\varepsilon= |f(1)- 1/2|/2.$ Then all functions $g$ within a distance $\varepsilon$ of $f$ fail to satisfy $g(1)>1/2,$ so $f$ is not on the boundary.

Comment: You should check what $X$ and $Y$ are in OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $f \in \partial Y$ if and only if for every $r > 0$ we have $B(f, r) \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ and $B(f, r) \cap Y^c \ne \emptyset$.

If $f \in \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) = \frac12\right\}$ then for every $r > 0$ the open ball $B(f, r)$ contains an element of $Y$:

Pick $c \in \langle 0, \frac12 + r\rangle \setminus \{-f(0)\}$ and notice that $g = f + c$ is in $Y$:

$$g(1) = f(1) + c > f(1) = \frac12$$

$$g(0) = f(0) + c \ne 0$$

Thus, $B(f, r) \cap Y \ne \emptyset$.

On the other hand, $f$ itself is in $Y^c$ so $B(f, r) \cap Y^c \ne \emptyset$.

Hence, $\left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) = \frac12\right\} \subseteq \partial Y$.

---

Now let $f \in \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) > \frac12 \text{ and } g(0) =
 0\right\}$.

For every $r > 0$ we have $f \in B(f, r) \cap Y^c$ so $B(f, r) \cap Y^c \ne \emptyset$.

On the other hand, $f + \frac{r}2 \in B(f, r) \cap Y$ so $B(f, r) \cap Y \ne \emptyset$.

Hence, $\left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) > \frac12 \text{ and } g(0) =
 0\right\} \subseteq \partial Y$.

---

Now consider $f \notin \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) = \frac12\right\} \cup \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) > \frac12 \text{ and } g(0) =
 0\right\}$.

If $f(1) > \frac12$, then we have $f(0) \ne 0$ so for $r < \min\left\{f(1) - \frac12, |f(0)|\right\}$ we have $B(f, r) \subseteq Y$.

Similarly, if $f(1) < \frac12$, then for $r < \frac12 - f(1)$ we have $B(f, r) \subseteq Y^c$.

In any case, $f \notin \partial Y$.

Therefore:

$$\partial Y = \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) = \frac12\right\} \cup \left\{g \in C[0,1]: g(1) > \frac12 \text{ and } g(0) =
 0\right\}$$